# JSON object returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am confused as to why this is alterting as "undefined". Any help would be much appreciated as I am stuck on an important project.

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON("item-data.json", function(results) {
        $.each(results, function(index) {
            alert(results[index].CatalogEntryView);
        });
    });
```

JSON Data is a BIG file. It starts out with the first object defined as "CatalogEntryView" with a long list of nested properties.

```
 {
   "CatalogEntryView": [
     {
      "CustomerReview": [
```

Using the following code recommended in one of the answers below returns the following to the console:

Recommended Code

```
 $.each(results.CatalogEntryView, function(index, item) {
        console.dir(item.CustomerReview); 
 });
```

[image: Console Output in Chrome]

Comment: We'll need more information on how your JSON file is structured and what do you mean by "returning".

Comment: It alerts "undefined"

Comment: If it starts out with `CatalogEntryView`, then that is what `index` is going to be. So `results[index]` is going to be `results['CatalogEntryView']` and thus `results['CatalogEntryView'].CatalogEntryView` is undefined as there is no such property

Comment: So just alert results[index] instead?

Comment: Your *each* function is expecting an array of json objects, but this nested object doesn't seem to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try this:

```
 $.each(results.CatalogEntryView, function(index, item) {
        console.dir(item.CustomerReview); 
 });
```

It should fit the structure of your json file. Another question is what you really want to get...

`results` from your code should be [iterable](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> jQuery.each( array, callback ) - a generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a
>   length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated
>   by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via
>   their named properties.

Comment: I will edit the post to show what showed up in the console

Comment: @SDH I checked it out. And what is wrong with that? It shows items from `"CustomerReview"` array. If you want 1 level higher - items from `"CatalogEntryView"` array - output just `item` like `console.dir(item)`.

Comment: `{...}` defines a level of deepness/nesting even if it doesn't have a name.

Comment: This was actually really helpful. Thanks